# IntelliJ editor sync error: find ./node_nix/bin: No such file or directory

Tags: daml

I am able to Run build command successfully. But when I am try to run sync command using IntelliJ editor getting error as `"find: ../node_nix/bin: No such file or directory" . Sync Failed.`

```
Version:
IntelliJ: Community 2019.3
DAML Version: 0.13.40
```

Please help...

Comment: Hey @Kunal. This sounds like a question about the DAML repository specifically, rather than help with the DAML language or SDK. Could you clarify which "Sync" command you're running? If it's Bazel, you might want to try downgrading to IntelliJ 2019.2 and trying again; the Bazel plugin doesn't support 2019.3 yet.

Comment: If you have trouble importing the DAML repository, you may want to have a second look at the instructions to set it up, here: https://github.com/digital-asset/daml#2-set-up-the-development-dependencies

Comment: Hi @SamirTalwar - I am running "Sync All" command.    Tools version are
IntelliJ: Community 2019.3
DAML Version: 0.13.40
Java - 1.8
bazel - 1.2.1
DAML version: 0.13.40

I am getting error when I run Sync ALL command using IntelliJ Id

Comment: @SamirTalwar :  stefanobaghino Update:

Now I am getting multiple errors like 
ERROR: While resolving toolchains for target //compiler/damlc/pkg-db:pkg-db: no matching toolchains found for types @rules_haskell//haskell:toolchain